# JavaCC: apply LOOKAHEAD number to all choices in a single choice list

Tags: javacc, ambiguity

With JavaCC, I want to have a lookahead of 3 for all choices in a single choice list.  That is, I could do:

```
LOOKAHEAD(3) A() | LOOKAHEAD(3) B | LOOKAHEAD(3) C
```

But I'd prefer to do something like:

```
LOOKAHEAD(3) ( (A) | B() | C() )
```

Looking in the `examples/JavaGrammars/1.5/Java1.5.jj` file in the JavaCC 5.0 examples/demos package, I see code<sup>*</sup> that's like:

```
( LOOKAHEAD(3) ( (A) | B() | C() ) )
```

However, that gets me the warning `Encountered LOOKAHEAD(...) at a non-choice location.  This will be ignored.` and otherwise has no effect.

<sup>*</sup>: Specifically, the `Modifiers` rule, line 1104.

Comment: The example you give from examples/JavaGrammars/1.5/Java1.5.jj is within a loop. The lookahead of 2 is used to decide whether to (re)enter the loop. The subsequent choices can obviously be decided with the default lookahead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is

```
LOOKAHEAD(3) A() | LOOKAHEAD(3) B() | C()
```

This means:

```
if the next three tokens are compatible with A()
    A()
else if the next three tokens are compatible with B()
    B()
else if the next token is compatible with C()
    C()
else error
```

See [the JavaCC lookahead tutorial](https://javacc.java.net/doc/lookahead.html).